# How to efficiently share a common parent atribute class by multiprocessing tasks?

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing

I have a class named "Problem", and another two called "Colony", and "Ant".

A "Problem" has an attribute of type "Colony", and each "Colony" has a list of "Ants".

Each Ant is thought as a Task to be run in a `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()` in a method in the "Problem" class, and when their method `__call__` is called, they must consult & modify an attribute `graph` in the "Problem" class, which would have to be accessed by every ant.

What would be the most efficient way to implement this?

I have thought of passing to each ant in the constructor method a copy of the graph, and then when they are finished, join all the subgraphs into a graph. But I think it would be better to somehow share the resource directly by all ants, like using "semaphore" style design.

Any ideas?.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If splitting the data and joining the results can be done reasonably, this is almost always going to be more efficient—and a lot simpler—than having them all fight over shared data.

---

There are cases where there is no reasonable way to do this (it's either very complicated, or very slow, to join the results back up). However, even in that case there can be a reasonable alternative: return "mutation commands" of some form. The parent process can then, e.g., iterate over the output queue and apply each result to the single big array.

---

If even that isn't feasible, then you need sharing. There are two parts to sharing: making the data itself sharable, and locking it.

Whatever your graph type is, it probably isn't inherently shareable; it's probably got internal pointers and so on. This means you will need to construct some kind of representation in terms of [`multiprocessing.Array`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects), or `multiprocessing.sharedctypes` around `Structure`s, or the like, or in terms of bytes in a file that each process can `mmap`, or by using whatever custom multiprocessing support may exist in modules like NumPy that you may be using. Then, all of your tasks can mutate the `Array` (or whatever), and at the end, if you need an extra step to turn that back into a useful graph object, it should be pretty quick.

Next, for locking, the really simple thing to do is create a single `multiprocessing.Lock`, and have each task grab the lock when it needs to mutate the shared data. In some cases, it can be more efficient to have multiple locks, protecting different parts of the shared data. And in some cases it can be more efficient to grab the lock for each mutation instead of grabbing it once for a whole "transaction" worth of sequences (but of course it may not be *correct*). Without knowing your actual code, there's no way to make a judgment on these tradeoffs; in fact, a large part of the art of shared-data threading is knowing how to work this stuff out. (And a large part of the reason shared-nothing threading is easier and usually more efficient is that you don't *need* to work this stuff out.)

---

Meanwhile, I'm not sure why you need an explicit `JoinableQueue` here in the first place. It sounds like everything you want can be done with a `Pool`. To take a simpler but concrete example:

```
a = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [9,10,11]]
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    b = pool.map(reversed, a, chunksize=1)
    c = [list(i) for i in b]
```

This is a pretty stupid example, but it illustrates that each task operates on one of the rows of `a` and returns something, which I can then combine in some custom way (by calling `list` on each one) to get the result I want.